# LaTex template for Bentham Science journal (Protein & Peptide Letters)

Tags: journal-publishing

does anyone have a LaTex template for Protein and Peptide Letter from Bentham Science? They only have doc file at the moment but they accept LaTex submission. Would really appreciate if someone shares a LaTex template for this journal or a similar template.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Did you ask the publisher what requirements they have regarding a LaTeX submission?

Comment: most likely they will just convert the tex source not actually typeset with it so just use `article` class and as few personal macros as possible,to make the conversion less stressful, don't try to make it look like the published journal. (This is just based on general principles about journal submission flows, I do not know anything about this particular journal)

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner they mentioned about accepting LaTex files but not detailed enough to state their requirements. They just attached a word file template for their journal. Already emailed/DM the publisher for their LaTex template but I have yet to receive any replies from them.

Comment: My *guess* it that it will be difficult for others to help you with this specific problem. I would start with a simple article document class and stick to common packages like amsmath etc. (maybe avoiding tikz). Then it will be easy later to adapt to more specific requorements.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner will do just what David also recommended. i guess i'll just have to start with the article document class. thanks guys!

Comment: Sounds good, you can also have a look at https://ctan.org/pkg/ieeetran.